# How to change the time between each bx-Slider slides after initial binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

On my page I have a few bx Sliders. They're set up like this:

```
$('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                mode: 'fade',
                speed: 2000,
                slideMargin: 160,
                pause: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1500)
            });
```

Is there any possibility to set the pause option of the slider for the first change on 2000, but from this point it should be a random time between 1500 and 5000. So is there any way to change the pause option after the first slide/fade?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the bx Slider has that type of support, here is a solution that might work. It is untested but might point you into the right direction:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    function Timer(timeout) { //timer function to keep track of slide speed.
        var self = this;
        var time = 0;
        this.interval = timeout ? timeout : 1000;   // Default

        this.run = function (runnable) {
            interval = setInterval(function () { runnable(self); time += 1; }, this.interval);
        };

        var pauseCalc = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1500); //You can do your pause calculations here

        if ($('#bxslider1').length > 0 && time == 0) { // Check if the contol exists and time == 0
            $('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                mode: 'fade',
                speed: 2000,
                slideMargin: 160,
                pause: pauseCalc // original pause
            }); 
        } else if (time == 2) {
            $('#bxslider1').unbind(); // Unbind the control first then re-bind
            $('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                mode: 'fade',
                speed: 2000,
                slideMargin: 160,
            pause: pauseCalc //Add new pause after 2 sec
        }); 

        clearInterval(interval); //Stop the timer;
    }
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
//invoke the timer
Timer.run(1000);
```